# Doubt with tools "rotate object" and automatic tracing mode

Tags: polygon, editing, rotate, tracing

I have a doubt with the edition of polygons. I have created many tables to digitize some archaeological surveys and I have encountered several problems. For reasons of the site, these surveys were not made from south to magnetic north, but slightly inclined (15º) to the east. At the time of digitizing I have a slight problem, I can not snap the vertices with an tracing mode, I have to do it manually and there is always some imperfection. If I have to do it manually with the other 99 tables it will take me forever.

Is there any way to join those vertices with the automatic tracing mode option? This function only works when I work with the north-south grids when moving the polygon, and not when using the rotate polygon tool.

I hope I have expressed myself well, I attach images to clarify the situation.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)[image]

Comment: Without more details, it's difficult to say. Can you provide your data (or a sample of it) for testing?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I do not know how I could provide the data or files necessary for you to test. Just tell me the way and I'll share it.
On the other hand, what I propose is to use the rotation tool together with the automatic tracing mode.